# How do we verify the value of $x$ particular that's been given as $f/k$ in this lecture?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, differential-equations, linear-systems

I was watching this lecture about Simple Harmonic Motion and how the friction plays a role in the SHM of a block connected to a spring that's connected to a wall. I don't understand how the value of $x$ particular has been acquired.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will be the 'guess' solution to the nonhomogenous second order differential equation listed at the top which is :$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + kx = f$$To form the general solution $x(t)$  of this you need to have to two things. The solution to the complimentary homogenous equation $$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + kx = 0$$and a guess solution known as $Y_p(t)$. The $x_p = \frac{f}{k}$ will be from the guess. I recommend using [this website](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx) if you wish to further your knowledge on finding the 'guess'.

EDIT: (The proof). As the equation is equal to $f$ which is not a function of $t$ then our guess $x_p(t)$ should be a constant, $A$. Putting this back into the equation we get $Ak = f$ and subsequently we can get $A = \frac{f}{k}$, and we can conclude that $x_p(t) = \frac{f}{k}$

Hope this helps :)